# Sending wrong paper size to printer

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

We have started a project for printing, however we are completely stuck when it comes to telling the printer what paper size is selected.

Everytime we select the paper size and hit print, the printer preview is showing A4 everytime and not our selected size although if we open the print preferences the correct size is selected.

```
namespace CPrint
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для ucPrint.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ucPrint : UserControl
    {
        bool SystemChange = false;
        double? PaperHeight = null;
        double? PaperWidth = null;
        public ucPrint()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            App.Localization.AddControls(this, new string[]
             {
                    "cHeader", "lPrinter", "lCopies","lLayout", "bPrintSettings","lColorManagement","lPrinterProfile", "lPositionSize", "cCenter", "lTop", "lLeft"
             });
        }

        public static BitmapSource ConvertColorProfile(BitmapSource bitmapSource, ColorContext sourceProfile, ColorContext destinationProfile)
        {
            var bitmapConverted = new ColorConvertedBitmap();
            bitmapConverted.BeginInit();
            bitmapConverted.Source = bitmapSource;
            //bitmapConverted.SourceColorContext = new ColorContext(PixelFormats.Pbgra32);//  bitmapSourceFrame.ColorContexts == null ? sourceProfile : bitmapSourceFrame.ColorContexts[0];
            bitmapConverted.SourceColorContext = sourceProfile;
            bitmapConverted.DestinationColorContext = destinationProfile;
            bitmapConverted.DestinationFormat = PixelFormats.Bgra32;
            bitmapConverted.EndInit();
            return bitmapConverted;
        }

        private void BPrint_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (cPrinter.SelectedItem == null) { MessageBox.Show("Printer not set"); return; }
            if (cPaperSize.SelectedItem == null) { MessageBox.Show("Paper size not set"); return; }


            double marging = 30;

            if (App.CurrentTemplateControl != null)
            {
                var img = App.CurrentTemplateControl.GetImage(true);
                if (img == null) return;
                var image = new Image() { Source = img };

                if (cColorProfile != null && cColorProfile.SelectedItem != null && cColorProfile.SelectedIndex > 0)
                {
                    Uri sourceProfileUri = new Uri((cColorProfile.SelectedItem as FileInfo).FullName);
                    image.Source = ConvertColorProfile(image.Source as BitmapSource, new ColorContext(PixelFormats.Pbgra32), new ColorContext(sourceProfileUri));
                }

                if (cMirror.IsChecked == true)
                {
                    var transformGroup = new TransformGroup();
                    transformGroup.Children.Add(new ScaleTransform(-1, 1, img.Width / 2, img.Height / 2));
                    image.RenderTransform = transformGroup;
                }
                PrintDialog printDialog2 = new PrintDialog();
                Size size = (Size)(cPaperSize.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem).DataContext;
                printDialog2.PrintQueue = new PrintQueue(new PrintServer(), cPrinter.Text);


                //if (printDialog2.ShowDialog() == true)
                //{
                //Size size = new Size(printDialog2.PrintableAreaWidth, printDialog2.PrintableAreaHeight);

                printDialog2.PrintTicket = new PrintTicket()
                {
                    PageMediaSize = new PageMediaSize(size.Width, size.Height)
                };
                //printDialog2.PrintTicket
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas()
                {
                    //Height = PrintContext.ToPx(size.Height),
                    //Width = PrintContext.ToPx(size.Width),
                    Height = size.Height,
                    Width = size.Width,
                    Background = Brushes.White
                };
                canvas.Children.Add(image);

                double scaleW = (size.Width - marging * 2) / img.Width;
                double scaleH = (size.Height - marging * 2) / img.Height;
                if (scaleW < 1 || scaleH < 1)
                {
                    Canvas.SetLeft(image, marging);
                    Canvas.SetTop(image, marging);
                    double scale = scaleW > scaleH ? scaleH : scaleW;
                    var transformGroup = new TransformGroup();
                    transformGroup.Children.Add(new ScaleTransform(scale, scale, 0, 0));
                    image.RenderTransform = transformGroup;
                }
                else if (cCenter.IsChecked == true)
                {
                    Canvas.SetLeft(image, size.Width / 2 - img.Width / 2);
                    Canvas.SetTop(image, size.Height / 2 - img.Height / 2);
                }
                else
                {
                    Canvas.SetLeft(image, marging);
                    Canvas.SetTop(image, marging);
                }
                printDialog2.PrintVisual(canvas, "Print");
                //}
            }


            return;

        }

        private void CPrinter_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SystemChange = true;
            var lastPrinterName = cPrinter.Text;
            cPrinter.Items.Clear();
            int index = -1;
            cPrinter.SelectedIndex = index;
            foreach (string strPrinter in System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
            {
                index++;
                cPrinter.Items.Add(strPrinter);
                if (strPrinter == lastPrinterName)
                    cPrinter.SelectedIndex = index;
            }
            SystemChange = false;
        }

        private void CPrinter_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0 && SystemChange == false)
            {
                var printer = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings();
                printer.PrinterName = e.AddedItems[0].ToString();
                var lastPaperName = cPaperSize.Text;
                cPaperSize.Items.Clear();
                int index = -1;
                cPaperSize.SelectedIndex = index;
                foreach (System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize paper in printer.PaperSizes)
                {
                    index++;
                    cPaperSize.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem() { Content = paper.PaperName, DataContext = new Size(paper.Width, paper.Height) });
                    if (paper.PaperName == lastPaperName)
                        cPaperSize.SelectedIndex = index;
                }
                Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultDirectPrinter = printer.PrinterName;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }
        }

        private void CPaperSize_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultDirectPaper = ((ComboBoxItem)e.AddedItems[0]).Content.ToString();
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }
        }

        public void UpdateControls()
        {
            SystemChange = true;

            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultDirectPrinter))
            {
                SystemChange = true;
                var lastPrinterName = cPrinter.Text;
                cPrinter.Items.Clear();
                int index = -1;
                cPrinter.SelectedIndex = index;
                foreach (string strPrinter in System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
                {
                    index++;
                    cPrinter.Items.Add(strPrinter);
                    if (strPrinter == Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultDirectPrinter)
                        cPrinter.SelectedIndex = index;
                }
                SystemChange = false;

                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultDirectPaper))
                {
                    var printer = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings();
                    printer.PrinterName = Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultDirectPrinter;
                    string lastPaperName = Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultDirectPaper;
                    cPaperSize.Items.Clear();
                    int indexP = -1;
                    cPaperSize.SelectedIndex = indexP;
                    foreach (System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize paper in printer.PaperSizes)
                    {
                        indexP++;
                        cPaperSize.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem() { Content = paper.PaperName, DataContext = new Size(paper.Width, paper.Height) });
                        if (paper.PaperName == lastPaperName)
                            cPaperSize.SelectedIndex = indexP;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultDirectColorProfile))
            {
                var lastValue = Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultDirectColorProfile;
                cColorProfile.Items.Clear();
                int index = -1;
                cColorProfile.SelectedIndex = index;
                cColorProfile.Items.Add("");
                index++;
                foreach (var file in App.Icc.items)
                {
                    index++;
                    cColorProfile.Items.Add(file);
                    if (file.FullName == lastValue)
                        cColorProfile.SelectedIndex = index;
                }
            }
            SystemChange = false;
        }

        private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void CColorProfile_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var lastValue = cColorProfile.Text;
            cColorProfile.Items.Clear();
            int index = -1;
            cColorProfile.SelectedIndex = index;
            cColorProfile.Items.Add("");
            index++;
            foreach (var file in App.Icc.items)
            {
                index++;
                cColorProfile.Items.Add(file);
                if (file.Name == lastValue)
                    cColorProfile.SelectedIndex = index;
            }
        }

        private void CColorProfile_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!SystemChange)
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultDirectColorProfile = (cColorProfile.SelectedItem as FileInfo)?.FullName;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect if we select A5, it tells the print driver to print A5,

If we select a custom "user defined" paper size, it tells the printer which size is selected. And not fixing this at A4 everytime

We cant seem to set the paper size outside the print dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I believe; following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.papersize?view=netframework-4.8) and [this MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.pagesettings.papersize?view=netframework-4.8) article; you are going to want to do something along the lines of:

```
System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize paperSize = new System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("custom", width, height);
PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = paperSize;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have walk through your code,

I think some event raise by front end (XAML) on specific use cases that is the overriding the actual value in "Properties.Settings.Default."

It would be better to resolve if you provide a XAML code for this issue.

I can look into it and will give you better solution.

You can share me code here is my skype : shsakariya